# How do I get the email address of the author of a SharePoint list item?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, author, sharepoint-object-model

As title says, I have access to the current listitem - and it's easy enough to get the author/created by name - but how do I retrieve the e-mail address of the author in C# from the object model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx) from a [SPFieldUserValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.aspx) object:

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue = 
    new SPFieldUserValue(web, item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString());
SPUser user = userValue.User;
string email = user.Email;
```

Comment: This is what sorted it in the end. Thanks for that Rich.